# Why would POST requests in Django work sometimes and not the other times? (It's almost random)

Tags: python, django, post, crud

I have a Django CRUD web app that is basically used to add values to the database, which are visible on the frontend when the page is refreshed and there is a button to edit that entry. It works perfectly fine 90% of the time. But there will be a random instance where someone adds something using the UI and it is added to the database but when refreshed, the entry disappears from the database! It's the most absurd thing I've ever seen. If something was wrong with the code wouldn't it never add it correctly. I'm just confused why it adds values fine 90% of the time but there's that few instances of disappearing entries.

```
def index(request, user, created_by):
    if request.POST:
        print(request.POST)
        selected_user = request.POST.get('name_user')
        selected_project = request.POST.get('name_project')
        print(selected_user)
        week_starting = request.POST.get('date')
        hours = request.POST.get('hours')
        activity = request.POST.get('activity')
        selected_tag = request.POST.get('tag')
        # check if record already exists for the same user and same week_starting and selected_project
        # if not then insert to DB
        # else don't insert, say record already exists
        if selected_tag == '':
            check_if_exists = TABLENAME.objects.filter(username=selected_user,
                                                                             week_starting=week_starting,
                                                                             project_id=selected_project, tag_id__isnull=True)
        else:
            check_if_exists = TABLENAME.objects.filter(username=selected_user,
                                                                             week_starting=week_starting,
                                                                             project_id=selected_project,
                                                                             tag_id=selected_tag)
        count = check_if_exists.count()
        print("at insert")
        print("how many same records already exist: ", count)
        if count < 1:
            selected_project_id = TABLENAME.objects.only('project_id').get(
                project_id=request.POST.get('project'))
            print(selected_project)
            if selected_tag == '':
                TABLENAME.objects.create(username=selected_user, project_id=selected_project_id,
                                                               week_starting=week_starting, forecast_hours=hours,
                                                               description=activity,
                                                               created_on=timezone.now(), created_by=created_by)
                add_status = "added - no tag"
            else:
                TABLENAME.objects.create(toggl_username=selected_user,
                                                               project_id=selected_project_id,
                                                               week_starting=week_starting, forecast_hours=hours,
                                                               description=activity, tag_id=selected_tag,
                                                               created_on=timezone.now(), created_by=created_by)
                add_status = "added - with tag"
            flash_text = 'Record inserted'
            print(add_status)
            # selected_tag = 0
            return render(request, 'hello_v2.html',
                          {'flash_text': flash_text, 'users': users, 'selected_user': selected_user,
                           'projects': projects, 'date': date, 'tags': tags,
                           'selected_tag': selected_tag, 'selected_project': selected_project})
            # add if tag is not empty then pass tags like here else don't - do the same thing for ID
        else:
            flash_text = 'Record already exists'
            return render(request, 'hello_v2.html',
                          {'flash_text': flash_text, 'users': users, 'selected_user': selected_user,
                           'projects': projects, 'date': date, 'tags': tags, 'selected_tag': selected_tag,
                           'selected_project': selected_project})

    else:
        print("Loading page")
        print(date)
        selected_tag = request.GET.get('tag_id')
        return render(request, 'hello_v2.html', {'users': users, 'date': date, 'projects': projects, 'tags': tags, 'selected_tag': selected_tag})
```

I'm tracking the POST requests by printing them and in the instances where the entry disappears from the database, I can't see the POST request printed... So I'm really confused
I also have an edit method which enables users to edit an entry, sometimes when users edit an entry then it disappears so maybe I have an issue there? But it's only some edits that cause that, not all.

Comment: If the post request isn't printing, are you sure it is even getting to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the request like this.

```
def index(request, user, created_by):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.POST)
        selected_user = reques
```

Comment: I agree. I bet there is a false positive in the post (whitespace, artifact) that is causing problems.

Comment: you should add an explanation along with the solution or refer to the Django documentation of `request.POST`.

Comment: That does sound like the way to go, but do you think just changing that should resolve the issue or would I have to deal with the whitespace, artifact, etc that might be causing the issue? Unfortunately, no way to test it since it only happens randomly. I have updated it to ```request.method == 'POST':```, just confirming if there are other things I should change/add ? Or that should take care of the false positives in the post? @Marc @arjun

Comment: @bourgeoisna the change in evaluation is huge and makes a lot of sense insofar as your problem.  Use of your original `if request.POST:` allows any/all false positives to be part of the eval.  Django will handle all the setting of data if you use available methods, but for understandable reasons will not alter original POST data until closer to saving (escape characters, etc).   Two things stand out in your code. 1.) Consider using CBVs and 2.) simplify the view A LOT. Keep views small and tight and make everything testable. There are a number of hot spots that I see consider linting the code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Probably not my best work. Will try to implement best standards as you recommend here. Thanks a lot!